# Compare json files

Tags: python, json, pycharm, file-comparison

I have two json files.

File1.json
File2.json

Using python, I want to compare both files and write differences in third file Output.json

Output file should be easy to read.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://dictdiffer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Check out [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should do what you're looking for, assuming I read the question right.

```
import json

data1 = json.load(open('data1.json'))
data2 = json.load(open('data2.json'))

for item in data1.keys():
    if data2[item] != data1[item]:
        print(f"{item} has differences")
```

Comment: Hi,

Above code is working fine on simple json format but my json file is one below format:

{
 "list": [{
  "id": "97c7d810-f101-11eb-ae60-39ee5de7b677",
  "original_statement": {
   "id": "2403002a-17a5-4cfc-b87b-7de693328362",
   "meta": {
    "createdAt": "2021-07-30T06:44:30.000Z"
   },
   "tags": [{
     "key": "entityType",
     "value": "medicalCondition"
    },
    {
     "key": "context",
     "value": "oblemsAsthmaMalignant neoplasm of sigmoid colon ﴾Noted 7/11/2016﴿Thyroid nodule"
    }
   ]
  }
 }]
}

your code result is list has differences.